# How to fetch numbers from a file and calculate using shell script

Tags: command-line, scripts

I have a file named numbers.txt. That contain some numbers like this

```
1568
14578
2365
41655
9965
...
...
```

I need to take sum of these numbers. How can i take this using a shell script??

Comment: how are the numbers separated? space? new line? comma?

Comment: Copy and paste the actual file to http://paste.ubuntu.com and give us the link

Comment: @SamFlynn When in doubt, check the question source. They were line-separated. I've formatted as code now.

Comment: Answered on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2702564/7552

Answer (score 5):

If your file is *huge* (eg `seq 1 100000000 > numbers.txt`), the traditional tools start to fall apart.

- [`awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}`](https://askubuntu.com/a/645857/449) takes 34s but "0%" RAM (not sure if that's accurate)
- [`perl -nle '$sum += $_ } END { print $sum' numbers.txt`](https://askubuntu.com/a/645844/449) took 27s and a tiny amount of RAM.
- [Jacob's Python](https://askubuntu.com/a/645841/449) takes 47s and 6GB of RAM (and 23s when run with `pypy`, same RAM)
- `numsum` was *awful*; it took 9m43s and 14GB of RAM to give an exponential number (the others replied with full long ints)
- Pure Bash would take forever-and-a-day to for-loop over them so I'm not attempting it

The alternative I offer an answer that can **add a hundred million integers in 6.4 seconds**...

... But it's written in C. Easy C. No strange requirements to build, or degree needed to understand it, but you do have to compile it and the filename is hardcoded into it (which you could fix)...

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;

    char line[100];
    unsigned long int total = 0;

    fp = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");

    while (fgets(line, 100, fp) != NULL) {
        total += atoi(line);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    printf("%li\n", total);

    return 0;
}
```

Save that as something like `add.c`, run `make add` and then `./add` to run.

Comment: Nice improvisation! +1 :)

Comment: 8 seconds on my elderly system!

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F' ' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {sum+=$i;} print sum}' <your_file> | tail -1
```

If there is another delimiter than `space`, use `-F'<your_delimiter>'`, eg: `-F':'`

---

Using `numsum` (`sudo apt-get install num-utils`)

```
numsum -r <your_file> | numsum
```

If there is another delimiter than `space`, use `-s <your_delimiter>`, eg: `-s ':'`

---

*Example*

```
% awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {sum+=$i;} print sum}' foo         
70131
106625020

% awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {sum+=$i;} print sum}' foo | tail -1
106625020

% numsum -r foo | numsum
106625020

% awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {sum+=$i;} print sum}' bar | tail -1
70131

% numsum -r foo | numsum
70131

% cat foo
1568 14578 2365 41655 9965
7673 8273923 98273293

% cat bar
1568
14578
2365
41655
9965
```

Comment: Note the input was line-separated, not space-separated. Question just wasn't formatted well.

Comment: @Oli That makes no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Using `perl` and assuming a space delimiter:

```
perl -MList::Util=sum -ne 'print sum(split())."\n"' numbers.txt
```

For a `,` delimiter use:

```
perl -MList::Util=sum -ne 'print sum(split(/,/))."\n"' numbers.txt
```

But prefer this [command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2702614/1154487) if they are each on it's own line:

```
perl -nle '$sum += $_ } END { print $sum'
```

Comment: Nice...I need to learn perl but damn I'm lazy

Comment: Doesn't work for multiple input lines.

Comment: @A.B. Fixed by adding a `"\n"` after each line. Actually you can even combine the first and last command to sum everything

Answer (score 1):

For line-separated input files, the following `awk` code works well:

> `awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}' numbers.txt`

It is reported that with some versions of `awk` there may be some unexpected behaviors if the sum is going to be more than 2147483647.

Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450799/shell-command-to-sum-integers-one-per-line) SO answer and its comments.

Answer (score 0):

In python:

```
python -c "print(sum(int(n) for n in open('f').read().split()))"
```

where f is the file(+path) between (single) quotes, e.g.:

```
python -c "print(sum(int(n) for n in open('/home/jacob/Bureaublad/file.txt').read().split()))"
```

The delimiter can be changed in the section `.split()`. If e.g. the delimiter is a comma, set: `.split(',')`. By default, the numbers are split by both `\n` and `" "`.

#### Explanation:

```
open('f').read().split()
```

reads the file, splits it into numbers (as strings)

```
(int(n) for n in...
```

converts the strings into numbers

```
print(sum(...
```

finally, sums the found numbers and prints the result

#### The test

The result on a file:

```
1 2 3 4 5 200 2345

2560
```

But also; since `split()` splits on `\n` as well:

```
1 
2
3
4
5
200
2345

2560
```

#### EDIT

Although a competition with Oli's answer on speed and resources would be a fatal mistake, *IF* the file would be huge, at least on use of resources, the script below would offer an important improvement. Although the script is faster then the one- liner in my original answer, the biggest improvement is on memory usage.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
total = 0
with open(sys.argv[1]) as lines:
    for l in lines:
        total = total+int(l)
print(total)
```

Save it as `addnumbers.py`, run it with the textfile as argument:

```
python3 <script> <file>
```

Comment: Note the input was line-separated, not space-separated. Question just wasn't formatted well.

Comment: @Oli Ah, luckily, in `python`, `split()` also splits on `\n` :)

Answer (score 0):

Using bc :

```
paste -sd"+" file | bc
```

Comment: On a bigger file, I get `Fatal error: Out of memory for malloc.`